# Optional "ifPresent" generic wildcard

Tags: java

I found in the  OpenJDK (11) the implementation of `Optional.ifPresent()` method. [Here it is](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java):

```
 public void ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (this.value != null) {
            action.accept(this.value);
        }
 }
```

And I can't understand why this particular template is written: `<? super T>`

For example, we have classes A, B, C:

```
private static class A {
    protected void call() {
        System.out.println("Call A");
    }
}
private static class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected void call() {
        System.out.println("Call B");
    }
}
private static class C extends B {
    @Override
    protected void call() {
        System.out.println("Call C");
    }
}
```

And some calling `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Optional<B> opt = Optional.of(new B());
        opt.ifPresent(A::call);
}
```

I could call my main method with  `opt.ifPresent(A::call);` and with  `opt.ifPresent(B::call);` and can't with  `opt.ifPresent(C::call);`. Ok, I understand that. But why exactly `<? super T>`? I can achieve the same behavior with `<T>` template. Can someone help me understand this and give me an example of why this is necessary?

**Update:**

Finally, I found an example where the `<T>` type isn't enough in the `ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> action)` signature.

**Example:**
Let's imagine that the signature of our method is:

```
 public void ifPresent(Consumer<T> action)
```

In this case we can't use the method that way:

```
 Optional<B> opt = Optional.of(new B());
 opt .ifPresent(new Consumer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(final Object obj) {
                //compiler error: 'java: incompatible types'
            }
 });
```

But in the case with:

```
public void ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> action)
```

it's possible, and code compiles without any error.

Comment: If it was simply `<T>` then you couldn't call `o.ifPresent(System.out::println)` if `o` was a `Optional<MyType>`, because there's no `println(MyType)`. But since there's a `println(Object)` and `Object` is a supertype of `MyType` the `<? super T>` makes `ifPresent` accept `println`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thank you for the answer, but o.ifPresent(System.out::println) works fine with declaration <T>.
https://github.com/volodya-lombrozo/myoptional/blob/master/src/com/github/volodya_lombrozo/Joachim.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a question of [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) of generic types.

Function types are contravariant in their parameters. If `B` is a subclass of `A`, then `Consumer<A>` could be considered a subclass of `Consumer<B>`: whenever you need a `Consumer<B>` you can use a `Consumer<A>`, because it accepts `A` as a parameter, so it accepts also `B`.

On the other hand functions are covariant in their return type: a `Supplier<B>` have a return value which can be cast to `A`, so you could consider it a subclass of `Supplier<A>`.

Unfortunately such definitions do not work well with mutable structures: if you allow `List<B>` to be a subclass of `List<A>` then you can write:

```java
final List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
final List<A> listA = listB;
listA.add(new A()); // it is no longer a List<B>
final B b = listB.get(0); // ClassCastException
```

Therefore Java chose invariant generics: `Consumer<B>` is neither a subclass nor a superclass of `Consumer<A>`. But we want to remember that `Consumer<B>` is *de facto* a subclass of `Consumer<A>` so we use bounds in the signatures of functions.

Of course one might write:

```java
public <U super T> void ifPresent(Consumer<U super T> action) { ... }
```

(the `T` parameter refers to the type parameter of `Optional<T>`), but `U` is never used in the signature. So we use the wildcard `? super T`.

Other languages like [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) allow to specify if it is safe to use a generic type in a covariant or contravariant way in the class definition. So Scala whould define:

```scala
def ifPresent(Consumer[T] action): Unit { ... }
```

since the compiler already knows, that the parameter `T` in `Consumer` is contravariant.

**Remark**: if you don't write to a `List`, you can also use it in a covariant way through the type `List<? extends A>`. The compiler will not allow you to call `add(new A())` on such an object, since `?` can also be a subclass of `A`, in which case the call would break the `List`. But a call to `get()` will certainly return something assignable to `A`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your answer is absolutely correct and it helped me find suitable examples. And now I understand how it works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it make Consumer<Object> works too.

For example

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MyClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       final MyOptional<String> opt = new MyOptional<>("");
       final Consumer<Object> c = MyClass::callObject;
       opt.ifPresent(MyClass::callCharSequence); //ok
       opt.ifPresent(MyClass::callString);  //ok
       opt.ifPresent(MyClass::callObject);  //ok, because here MyClass::callObject is casted to Consumer<String> by the compiler automattically
       opt.ifPresent(c);  //won't ok
   }

   static void callString(String a) {
   }

   static void callCharSequence(CharSequence a) {
   }

   static void callObject(Object a) {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but your code works fine with <T> declaration too.
https://github.com/volodya-lombrozo/myoptional/blob/master/src/com/github/volodya_lombrozo/Vipcxj.java

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the base class of your optional in the declaration like this:

```
Optional<? extends A> opt = Optional.of(new B());
opt.ifPresent(A::call);
```

This would allow **any** sub class of type A to get in the optional object and interact with it. This allows more flexibility into what can be provided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your code doesn't compile at first line. Declaration of the class is 'Optional<T>' . You just can't do that.

Comment: https://github.com/volodya-lombrozo/myoptional/blob/master/src/com/github/volodya_lombrozo/Lalonde.java

Comment: To an `Optional<? extends A>` you can assign any `Optional<X>`, where `X` is a subclass of `A`. The code compiles.

Comment: As @PiotrP.Karwasz says, the code compiles and the output would print "Call B" in the console.

Comment: @P.Lalonde Yes, I'm sorry, my mistake. The code compiles. But, ok, I could wrire "<? extends A>", and what? I could achive the same with simple "<A>". And this would allow any sub class of type A too. My original question about parameter "Consumer<? super T> action" in "ifPresent" method. Why they wrote exactly <? super T>?

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo: you can also write `Optional<A> opt = Optional.of(new B());` thanks to the compiler that chooses the correct type parameter for `of`. If you specify it explicitly `Optional<A> opt = Optional.<B>of(new B());` will not compile.